# Не корректно работает задача на выбрасывание монет.

Tags: c

Есть программа которая моделирует подкидывание монеты. Проблема в том, что по логике должно выбрасывать приблизительно 50 на 50 (Орёл-Решка), но почему то соотношение приблизительно 30 на 70, почему так можете объяснить? (Devc++, win7)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int flip(void);

main()
{

  srand(time(NULL));

  int sumReshka = 0, sumOrel = 0;

  for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
  {

    if (flip() == 0)
    {
      sumReshka++;
      printf("Reshka\n");
    }
    else
    {
      sumOrel++;
      printf("Orel\n");
    }
  }

  printf("Kol-vo reshek - %d, Kol-vo orlov - %d\n", sumReshka, sumOrel);

  system("PAUSE");
}

int flip(void) 
{ 
  if ((rand() % 2) == 1)
  return 1;
  else if ((rand() % 2) == 0)
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Интересно, как вы смогли это вообще откомпилировать? У вас же нету `return`'а в функции `flip`.

Comment: @VladD 
warning C4715: flip: значение возвращается не при всех путях выполнения.

Comment: @manking: интересно, что возвращается в этом случае из функции? случайный мусор?

Comment: Нет, неправильно сказал. Всё таки мусор. 
Если внутри функции создать и инициализировать например std::string то возвратится адрес этой, первой переменной.

Если после последнего return в функции инициализовать массив, то возвратится адрес первого элемента этого массива. Если это делать до, возвратится 0.

Comment: @manking, ЕМНИП на PC возвратом в общем случае будет считаться значение ax/eax/ax:dx/eax:edx (в зависимости от типа возврата). А что в них попадёт - дело случая и компиляторного оптимизатора :))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

вместо

```
int flip(void) 
{ 
  if ((rand() % 2) == 1)
  return 1;
  else if ((rand() % 2) == 0)
  return 0;
}
```

вам нужно написать

```
int flip(void) 
{ 
  return (rand() % 2);

}
```

В первом варианте вы вызываете rand() дважды. То есть орел выпадает в 50% случаев, а если не выпадает, то вы вызываете rand() еще раз и возвращаете то, что получается в итоге, то есть еще один результат rand() % 2. Поэтому орел у вас в среднем бывает в 75% случаев

Comment: Я понял, спасибо.